# CryptographicException: Access denied - How to give access on User store?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, security

I am trying to load a certificate from a pfx file in a WPF application and it gives me an access denied error.

```
using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(certificatePath))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        buffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    }
}

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(buffer, password);
```

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied.
>   at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet,
>   SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[]
>   rawData, String password)    at
>   HelloWorld.HelloClient.Models.Infrastructure.ReadCertificateFromPfxFile(String
>   certificatePath, String password)

The last line in snippet is causing an exception, and if I run it as an administrator it works fine. The issue seems to be the default constructor of X509Certificate2 tries to put private key in the user store. I am not using web application. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951729/x509certificate-constructor-exception) post doesn't resolve my issue. I think the current user might not have access to his own private key store. But how can I give that access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X509Certificate Constructor Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951729/x509certificate-constructor-exception)

Comment: @MethodMan Its talking about web application and fixes in the IIS. I have WPF app how can I give permission to user store?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting a fix if someone looking for a solution for similar issue. I ran [sysinternal process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and realized the constructor call was creating a key in machine key folder and gave user access to write on machine key.

Comment: This was my problem to. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: could you explain more? I don't yet get how you solved the problem

Answer (score 11):

In my situation, it was due to the lack of *write* access to the **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys** folder.

My user was having only having the **Read** Access and once I granted the **Write** access it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the same `CryptographicException: Access denied` error when trying to load `X509Certificate2`, the solution is to grant read/write to the *MachineKeys * directory.

1. open a CMD or Powershell with **Admin** priv.
2. execute below command to grant *everyone* read/write: `icacls C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys /inheritance:r /grant Administrators:F /grant:r Everyone:RW`

More about permission on this dir: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/default-permissions-machinekeys-folders

Comment: Note: Those group / user names are specific to the current culture set,
use ```icacls C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys /inheritance:r /grant Administratoren:F /grant:r Jeder:RW``` for german language, eg.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone, "CryptographicException: Access denied" can be caused by lack of space in the disc, that was my case.

Answer (score -1):

I found it's easier to use the p12 certificate because it doesn't use the key store.
I [used firefox to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819079/convert-pfx-format-to-p12/51212554#51212554) pfx to p12.