# Android : Check the validity of a PFX certificate

Tags: java, android, certificate, pfx, checkvalidity

How could I check the validity of a PFX certificate programmatically using java?

I found various ways to do this (like using [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl)), but none using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using boucycastle libraries. Check below github project for the same which read the p12 file and get the certificate details.

> https://github.com/rosmahajan/java-read-p12

It is simple java class loading the p12/pfx file and read the certificate details. Once you get the x509Certificate object try below command to check the validity of certificate

```
x509.checkValidity();
```

Sometime renaming pfx file to p12 works as both are PKCS#12 file but if renaming doesn't work , try below to convert pfx to p12 using keytool

```
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore new.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -srckeystore original.pfx
```

For more information: 
[convert pfx format to p12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819079/convert-pfx-format-to-p12)