# Error code: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE installed SSL Certificate on Tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat, installation, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have bought a SSL Certificate from Comodo for my domain. The files which Comodo had provide me is:

1. SSL_PrivateKEY_www_my-domain_com.txt
2. SSL_CSR_www_my-domain_com.txt
3. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
4. USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
5. SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
6. www_my-domain_com.crt

After a research, I found this [Steps to create a .jks keystore using .key and .crt files...](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/steps-to-create-a-jks-keystore-using-key-and-crt-files), I using the 3,4 and 5 crt files and I am creating the cert.pem, then I am using the 1 crt to create the key.pem. After that, I am creating the jks as the guide says. Next, I am importing the 6 crt file in the keystore, like that:

```
keytool -import -alias mykey -file www_my-domain_com.crt -keystore www_my-domain_com.jks
```

Afterwards, I am using the [keystore explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) to convert my keystore to PKCS12. Finally I am uploading the file at my server and here is my tomcat 8, connector:

```
<Connector port="9443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
           minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
           keyAlias="server" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
           keystoreFile="/home/test/ssls/www_my-domain_com.jks"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

Restarting my tomcat and then the error which I am getting at the firefox

> Error code: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE

I also use the KeyStore Explorer to examine the ssl and the error which are showing there is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.kse.utilities.ssl.SslUtils.readSSLConnectionInfos(SslUtils.java:116)
    at org.kse.gui.dialogs.DExaminingSsl$ExamineSsl.run(DExaminingSsl.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution, after made contact with the SSL Certificate provider, which is:

1. Firstly, I must create a bundle text file with name my.bundle with the following order:

> - SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
> - USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
> - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

2. Secondly, you must run with OpenSSL the following command:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey my.key -certfile my.bundle
>   -out my.pfx

Where the my.crt is the www_my-domain_com.crt, the my.key is your private key and the my.bundle is the file which we have made in the previous step.

3. Next step is to run the command:

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore  pkcs12FileName.p12 
>   -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore  jksFileName.jks -deststoretype jks

Here the **pkcs12FileName.p12** is the file which produced from the previous step, rename it to p12([convert pfx format to p12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819079/convert-pfx-format-to-p12))

4. Following step just convert the jks, which exported from the previous step to type pkcs12 with the help of the [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/).
5. Finally, the tomcat connector in the conf/server.xml is:

   > Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150"
   >   minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false"
   >   disableUploadTimeout="true" SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100"
   >   scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
   >   keystoreFile="/opt/sslcertificates/www_my-domain_com.jks"
   >   keystorePass="mypassword"

And it works fine!